# Dumping of complex table and schema names on Windows is not supported. Phppgadmin. Export

Tags: sql, postgresql, phppgadmin

I have a database named **Extension**
A schema named **public**
A tables named **extension** and **mfo_3**

Here's what happen. When I try to export the database from the schema not the public schema in phppgadmin, It works!

But when I tried to to export within the schema or the public schema. Sample, I tried to export the table named mfo_3's data, I get an error

```
 Dumping of complex table and schema names on Windows is not supported. Phppgadmin.
```

Is there any solution for me to export my specific table's data?

BTW, I'm using the version 9.3.0 of PostgreSQL

Comment: did you get any solution? I have also faced this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I am also getting same error in phpPgAdmin.

But there is a command line way to export:

Open command window and change directory to C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin

To export whole database run: `pg_dump.exe mydb > db.sql`

If pg_dump is using operating system username instead of PostgreSql db username, 
    use -U switch like: `pg_dump.exe -U dbusername mydb > db.sql`

Reference: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html

Answer (score -2):

<strike>This error only appears when underline exists in the table name. Rename the table and try again.</strike>

### Edit:

This error only appears when you want to dump a part of database (on windows). Try again with entire database and extract the specific part from the dump.